# Sed substitutes just once instead of multiple times

Tags: xml, sed, substitution

I've got an XML-file with lots of the following code:

```
<BankAccount code="NL18INGB0001234567">
<BankAccountType code="NL">
<Description/>
```

I need to replace `code="NL"` with `code="IBA"`, but only when the `BankAccount` has `INGB000` in it. I use the following sed command:

```
sed 'N;s/\(INGB000[0-9].*NL\)/\1_OUD/g;s/NL_OUD/IBA/g' file1.xml > file2.xml
```

The problem is that this command only replaces the first one but not all the other ones.

I expected the `-g` option to do a global match, but that didn't work.

I also tried:

```
sed ':a;N;ta;s/\(INGB000[0-9].*NL\)/\1_OUD/g;s/NL_OUD/IBA/g' file1.xml > file2.xml
```

What am I doing wrong?

Input:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<eExact xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="eExact-Schema.xsd">
    <Accounts>
        <Account code="1206" status="A" type="C">
            <Name>John Doe</Name>
            <Contacts>
                <Contact default="1" gender="M" status="A">
                    <LastName>Client: 10000</LastName>
                    <Initials/>
                    <Addresses>
                        <Address type="V">
                            <AddressLine1>one-way-street</AddressLine1>
                            <PostalCode>1000 AB</PostalCode>
                            <City>Simcity 1</City>
                            <Country code="NL"/>
                        </Address>
                    </Addresses>
                </Contact>
            </Contacts>
            <Debtor code="1206" number="1206">
                <BankAccounts>
                    <BankAccount code="NL93INGB0001234567">
                        <BankAccountType code="NL">
                            <Description/>
                        </BankAccountType>
                        <Bank code="">
                            <Name/>
                            <IBAN>NL93INGB0001234567</IBAN>
                        </Bank>
                        <SDDMandate>
                            <MndtId>02001234-0000004</MndtId>
                            <DtOfSgntr>2000-11-01</DtOfSgntr>
                            <LclInstrm>Core</LclInstrm>
                            <LastSDDDt/>
                        </SDDMandate>
                    </BankAccount>
                </BankAccounts>
                <SendReminder>1</SendReminder>
            </Debtor>
        </Account>

        <Account code="1123" status="A" type="C">
            <Name>Johny Doe</Name>
            <Contacts>
                <Contact default="1" gender="V" status="A">
                    <LastName>Client: 10001</LastName>
                    <Addresses>
                        <Address type="V">
                            <AddressLine1>one-way-street</AddressLine1>
                            <PostalCode>1000 AB</PostalCode>
                            <City>Simcity 2</City>
                            <Country code="NL"/>
                        </Address>
                    </Addresses>
                </Contact>
            </Contacts>
            <Debtor code="1123" number="1123">
                <BankAccounts>
                    <BankAccount code="NL25RABO0123456789">
                        <BankAccountType code="NL">
                            <Description/>
                        </BankAccountType>
                        <Bank code="">
                            <Name/>
                            <IBAN>NL25RABO0123456789</IBAN>
                        </Bank>
                        <SDDMandate>
                            <MndtId>02001234-0000003</MndtId>
                            <DtOfSgntr>2000-02-03</DtOfSgntr>
                            <LclInstrm>Core</LclInstrm>
                            <LastSDDDt/>
                        </SDDMandate>
                    </BankAccount>
                </BankAccounts>
                <SendReminder>1</SendReminder>
            </Debtor>
        </Account>
        <Account code="1109" status="A" type="C">
            <Name>Joan Doe</Name>
            <Contacts>
                <Contact default="1" gender="V" status="A">
                    <LastName>Client: 10002</LastName>
                    <Initials/>
                    <Addresses>
                        <Address type="V">
                            <AddressLine1>one-way-street</AddressLine1>
                            <PostalCode>1000 AB</PostalCode>
                            <City>Simcity 1</City>
                            <Country code="NL"/>
                        </Address>
                    </Addresses>
                </Contact>
            </Contacts>
            <Debtor code="1109" number="1109">
                <BankAccounts>
                    <BankAccount code="NL46RABO0123456789">
                        <BankAccountType code="NL">
                            <Description/>
                        </BankAccountType>
                        <Bank code="">
                            <Name/>
                            <IBAN>NL46RABO0123456789</IBAN>
                        </Bank>
                        <SDDMandate>
                            <MndtId>02001234-0000002</MndtId>
                            <DtOfSgntr>2000-11-01</DtOfSgntr>
                            <LclInstrm>Core</LclInstrm>
                            <LastSDDDt/>
                        </SDDMandate>
                    </BankAccount>
                </BankAccounts>
                <SendReminder>1</SendReminder>
            </Debtor>
        </Account>
        <Account code="1631" status="A" type="C">
            <Name>Flint</Name>
            <Contacts>
                <Contact default="1" gender="V" status="A">
                    <LastName>Client: 10003</LastName>
                    <Initials/>
                    <Addresses>
                        <Address type="V">
                            <AddressLine1>one-way-street</AddressLine1>
                            <PostalCode>1000 AB</PostalCode>
                            <City>Simcity 3</City>
                            <Country code="NL"/>
                        </Address>
                    </Addresses>
                </Contact>
            </Contacts>
            <Debtor code="1631" number="1631">
                <BankAccounts>
                    <BankAccount code="NL10INGB0001234567">
                        <BankAccountType code="NL">
                            <Description/>
                        </BankAccountType>
                        <Bank code="">
                            <Name/>
                            <IBAN>NL10INGB0001234567</IBAN>
                        </Bank>
                        <SDDMandate>
                            <MndtId>02001234-0000001</MndtId>
                            <DtOfSgntr>2000-07-05</DtOfSgntr>
                            <LclInstrm>Core</LclInstrm>
                            <LastSDDDt/>
                        </SDDMandate>
                    </BankAccount>
                </BankAccounts>
                <SendReminder>1</SendReminder>
            </Debtor>
        </Account>
    </Accounts>
</eExact>
```

Desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eExact xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="eExact-Schema.xsd">
  <Accounts>
    <Account code="1206" status="A" type="C">
      <Name>John Doe</Name>
      <Contacts>
        <Contact default="1" gender="M" status="A">
          <LastName>Client: 10000</LastName>
          <Initials/>
          <Addresses>
            <Address type="V">
              <AddressLine1>one-way-street</AddressLine1>
              <PostalCode>1000 AB</PostalCode>
              <City>Simcity 1</City>
              <Country code="NL"/>
            </Address>
          </Addresses>
        </Contact>
      </Contacts>
      <Debtor code="1206" number="1206">
        <BankAccounts>
          <BankAccount code="NL93INGB0001234567">
            <BankAccountType code="IBA">
              <Description/>
            </BankAccountType>
            <Bank code="">
              <Name/>
              <IBAN>NL93INGB0001234567</IBAN>
            </Bank>
            <SDDMandate>
              <MndtId>02001234-0000004</MndtId>
              <DtOfSgntr>2000-11-01</DtOfSgntr>
              <LclInstrm>Core</LclInstrm>
              <LastSDDDt/>
            </SDDMandate>
          </BankAccount>
        </BankAccounts>
        <SendReminder>1</SendReminder>
      </Debtor>
    </Account>
    <Account code="1123" status="A" type="C">
      <Name>Johny Doe</Name>
      <Contacts>
        <Contact default="1" gender="V" status="A">
          <LastName>Client: 10001</LastName>
          <Addresses>
            <Address type="V">
              <AddressLine1>one-way-street</AddressLine1>
              <PostalCode>1000 AB</PostalCode>
              <City>Simcity 2</City>
              <Country code="NL"/>
            </Address>
          </Addresses>
        </Contact>
      </Contacts>
      <Debtor code="1123" number="1123">
        <BankAccounts>
          <BankAccount code="NL25RABO0123456789">
            <BankAccountType code="NL">
              <Description/>
            </BankAccountType>
            <Bank code="">
              <Name/>
              <IBAN>NL25RABO0123456789</IBAN>
            </Bank>
            <SDDMandate>
              <MndtId>02001234-0000003</MndtId>
              <DtOfSgntr>2000-02-03</DtOfSgntr>
              <LclInstrm>Core</LclInstrm>
              <LastSDDDt/>
            </SDDMandate>
          </BankAccount>
        </BankAccounts>
        <SendReminder>1</SendReminder>
      </Debtor>
    </Account>
    <Account code="1109" status="A" type="C">
      <Name>Joan Doe</Name>
      <Contacts>
        <Contact default="1" gender="V" status="A">
          <LastName>Client: 10002</LastName>
          <Initials/>
          <Addresses>
            <Address type="V">
              <AddressLine1>one-way-street</AddressLine1>
              <PostalCode>1000 AB</PostalCode>
              <City>Simcity 1</City>
              <Country code="NL"/>
            </Address>
          </Addresses>
        </Contact>
      </Contacts>
      <Debtor code="1109" number="1109">
        <BankAccounts>
          <BankAccount code="NL46RABO0123456789">
            <BankAccountType code="NL">
              <Description/>
            </BankAccountType>
            <Bank code="">
              <Name/>
              <IBAN>NL46RABO0123456789</IBAN>
            </Bank>
            <SDDMandate>
              <MndtId>02001234-0000002</MndtId>
              <DtOfSgntr>2000-11-01</DtOfSgntr>
              <LclInstrm>Core</LclInstrm>
              <LastSDDDt/>
            </SDDMandate>
          </BankAccount>
        </BankAccounts>
        <SendReminder>1</SendReminder>
      </Debtor>
    </Account>
    <Account code="1631" status="A" type="C">
      <Name>Flint</Name>
      <Contacts>
        <Contact default="1" gender="V" status="A">
          <LastName>Client: 10003</LastName>
          <Initials/>
          <Addresses>
            <Address type="V">
              <AddressLine1>one-way-street</AddressLine1>
              <PostalCode>1000 AB</PostalCode>
              <City>Simcity 3</City>
              <Country code="NL"/>
            </Address>
          </Addresses>
        </Contact>
      </Contacts>
      <Debtor code="1631" number="1631">
        <BankAccounts>
          <BankAccount code="NL10INGB0001234567">
            <BankAccountType code="IBA">
              <Description/>
            </BankAccountType>
            <Bank code="">
              <Name/>
              <IBAN>NL10INGB0001234567</IBAN>
            </Bank>
            <SDDMandate>
              <MndtId>02001234-0000001</MndtId>
              <DtOfSgntr>2000-07-05</DtOfSgntr>
              <LclInstrm>Core</LclInstrm>
              <LastSDDDt/>
            </SDDMandate>
          </BankAccount>
        </BankAccounts>
        <SendReminder>1</SendReminder>
      </Debtor>
    </Account>
  </Accounts>
</eExact>
```

This doesn't work:

```
sed '/BankAccount.*INGB000/,$ s/BankAccountType code="NL"/BankAccountType code="IBA"/g' file1.xml > file2.xml
```

This replaces all the code=NL after the first INGB000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/BankAccount.*INGB000/,$ s/code="NL"/code="IBA"/g' file1.xml > file2.xml
```

Or if you meant that you want to change `code="NA...` to `code="IBA...`, omit the closing quotes:

```
sed '/BankAccount.*INGB000/,$ s/code="NL/code="IBA/g' file1.xml > file2.xml
```

**EDIT:**

I'm still guessing at the output you want, but try this:

```
sed '/BankAccount code=".*INGB000/{N;s/code="NL"/code="IBA"/;}' file1.xml > file2.xml
```

Comment: Not good. In the XML is another branch:
<BankAccountType code="NL">
Your code also substitutes the "NL" in this branch and I don't want that.

Comment: @Apojoost: When you said _"all the other ones"_, I assumed you meant all the other ones. Perhaps you could edit your question to add a better example of the input, along with the output you want.

Comment: Sorry, this worked if I change it More specific: sed '/BankAccount.*INGB000/,$ s/BankAccountType code="NL"/BankAccountType code="IBA"/g' DEBITR_2016.08\ file1 > file2

Comment: I thought is worked but I didn't look at the outcome properly. Your answer replaces all the code=NL after the first INGB000. Can you help me a little bit further?

Comment: could you please help me again?

Comment: @Apojoost: Your question contains an example of input. **Could you edit the question to add the corresponding desired output?**

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I updated my question with the input file and the desired output. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Apojoost: **The sed command in my edit of Oct 19 turns your input into your desired output** (apart from the whitespace differences you left in, and the trivial differences in the first line). I give up.

Comment: Sorry. You're right. I didn't see the post from 19 Oct. It works.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

In my opinion you're using the wrong tool for the job. In most cases, [you shouldn't try to parse XML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

For this minor change you could use something like [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php)...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <BankAccount code="NL18INGB000ABCDEFG">
        <BankAccountType code="NL">
            <Description/>
        </BankAccountType>
    </BankAccount>
    <BankAccount code="NL18INGBXXX1234567">
        <BankAccountType code="NL">
            <Description/>
        </BankAccountType>
    </BankAccount>
    <BankAccount code="NL18INGB0001234567">
        <BankAccountType code="NL">
            <Description/>
        </BankAccountType>
    </BankAccount>
</doc>
```

**xmlstarlet command**

```
xml.exe ed -u "//BankAccount[contains(@code,'INGB000')]/BankAccountType/@code" -v "IBA" input.xml
```

**XML Output**

```
<doc>
  <BankAccount code="NL18INGB000ABCDEFG">
    <BankAccountType code="IBA">
      <Description/>
    </BankAccountType>
  </BankAccount>
  <BankAccount code="NL18INGBXXX1234567">
    <BankAccountType code="NL">
      <Description/>
    </BankAccountType>
  </BankAccount>
  <BankAccount code="NL18INGB0001234567">
    <BankAccountType code="IBA">
      <Description/>
    </BankAccountType>
  </BankAccount>
</doc>
```

You could also use XSLT. This is what I prefer.

**XSLT 1.0** (Could be processed using xmlstarlet or another processor. I used [Saxon-HE](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) (java from the command line) for testing.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="BankAccount[contains(@code,'INGB000')]/BankAccountType/@code">
    <xsl:attribute name="code">IBA</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is the same using the input from the xmlstarlet example.